# Python tbselenium Display is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, tor

I want to run a Tor session on a headless computer and I'm using the code from https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium/blob/master/examples/headless.py

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
from tbselenium.utils import start_xvfb, stop_xvfb
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath


def headless_visit(tbb_dir):
    out_img = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), "headless_screenshot.png")
    # start a virtual display
    xvfb_display = start_xvfb()
    with TorBrowserDriver(tbb_dir) as driver:
        driver.load_url("https://check.torproject.org")
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file(out_img)
        print("Screenshot is saved as %s" % out_img)

    stop_xvfb(xvfb_display)

def main():
    desc = "Headless visit and screenshot of check.torproject.org using XVFB"
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=desc)
    parser.add_argument('tbb_path')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    headless_visit(args.tbb_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But it raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 24, in main
    headless_visit(args.tbb_path)
  File "test.py", line 10, in headless_visit
xvfb_display = start_xvfb()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tbselenium/utils.py", line 33, in start_xvfb
    xvfb_display = Display(visible=0, size=(win_width, win_height))
NameError: name 'Display' is not defined
```

I'm using:

- python 3.8.5
- geckodriver v 0.17.0
- tor browser v 10.0.5

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a missing python package '***pyvirtualdisplay***'

solution:

```
pip3 install pyvirtualdisplay
```

cause:
If you look at the ***utils.py*** file referenced in the error you will find that the import of ***pyvirtualdisplay*** is nested in a try block with an exception handler that silently passes.  The comment suggests it is only needed for tests but that is obviously not true in our case.